# MS spark utilities - file move error using msspark.fs.mv

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, mssparkutils

Am in Synapse notebook, using pyspark to move file using `msspark.fs.mv(src, dest, True)`

Link to ms doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python#move-file

Code:

```
filepath = "abfss://raw@xxxxdev001.blob.core.windows.net/SASDatFiles/test_sep22.sas7bdat "
movepath = "abfss://raw@xxxxdev001.blob.core.windows.net/SASDatFiles/Processed/test_sep22.sas7bdat"
mssparkutils.fs.mv(filepath,movepath, True)
```

Error:

```
**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.fs.mv.
: Operation failed: "An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.", 400, PUT, https://xxxxdev001.blob.core.windows.net/raw/SASDatFiles/Processed/test_sep22.sas7bdat?timeout=90, , ""
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.renamePath(AbfsClient.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.rename(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.rename(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:354)
    at com.microsoft.spark.notebook.msutils.impl.MSFsUtilsImpl.mvWithinFileSystem(MSFsUtilsImpl.scala:128)
    at com.microsoft.spark.notebook.msutils.impl.MSFsUtilsImpl.mv(MSFsUtilsImpl.scala:259)
    at mssparkutils.fs$.mv(fs.scala:22)
    at mssparkutils.fs.mv(fs.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)**
```

Notebook running under my credentials, i got owner / blob contributor role assigned on **Azure Data Lake Gen 2**.
I can move files with my credentials in Storage Explorer ... no issues.

Any clues of the error?

Comment: How is the notebook connecting to data lake. When you run the notebook, it doesn't inherit your access to the data lake.

Comment: Notebook is part of Synapse pipeline, Synapase got 'Blob Data Contributor' on data lake

Answer (score 0):

**I try to reproduce same thing in my environment. I Got this output.**

*Configure your storage account as per below syntax:*

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net","<Access_key>") 


mssparkutils.fs.mv("abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/vamsiba.sas7bdat","abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder>")
```

[image]

**Or**

*If you want to copy data , use `mssparkutils.fs.cp` as shown in the below code:*

```
mssparkutils.fs.cp("abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/vamsiba.sas7bdat","abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder>")
```

[image]

**Note:**

**Source location:** `abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/vamsiba.sas7bdat`

**Destination location:**

```
abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder>
```

Before running the code or (Moving the file) make sure to check destination location should not contain the same **file name** as `vamsiba.sas7bdat` in the folder location otherwise you will get an error.